# insert value from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables `TEACHERS` and `ABSENCES` they both have column `unitid` so if `unitid` at `TEACHERS` table is `1` I want to insert that number `1` to `unitid` in `ABSENCES` table:

I think the query should look something like this

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

INSERT INTO ABSENCES (unitid)
select unitid
from TEACHERS
where unitid = teachers id here(please advise what i should put here)
```

Furthermore, my application is on PHP so maybe i can use if statements or something

---

Edit:

I just want to assign the value of unitid in teachers to unitid in absences.

The idea is this: Unit id 1 (means teacher teaches maths) so when i put unitid 1 to absences means that the student was absent in maths.

The query that already exists is this:

mysql_query("insert into absences (student_id, date) values ('".$_GET['student_id']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");

### i want it to be more specific to add also unitid which it takes from teachers

MORE SPECIFICALLY TABLES ARE:

`SUBJECTS       ABSENCES         TEACHERS
unitid          absence_id       username
unitname        student_id       password
                date              unitid
                unitid`

- The sbuject with unitid 1 has unitname maths.
- The teacher that has unitid 1 means he teaches maths
- The absence that has unit id 1 means the absence was taken in maths

Comment: Do you want to link the 2 table entries when inserting or are you asking how to query the table ?

Comment: Does the related row in `ABSENCES` already exist where you would `UPDATE` it or are you truly `INSERT`ing a new row?

Comment: i just want to assign the value of unitid in teachers to unitid in absences.

The idea is this: Unit id 1 (means teacher teaches maths) so when i put unitid 1 to absences means that the student was absent in maths.

The query that already exists is this:

`mysql_query("insert into absences (student_id, date) values ('".$_GET['student_id']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");`

i want it to be more specific to add also unitid which it takes from teachers @david @michael

Comment: @DiellAbazi since you updated it, it makes even less sense to me.  If the absences is about student absenses then what does teachers have anything to do with it?

Comment: @devon teachers are the ones that take absences. So if unitid at teachers is 1 that teacher teachs maths so when he takes absences the absences will only take place on maths and no other unit.

Comment: @DiellAbazi, you need to work on your table structure and readability.  Someone from the outside looking in should understand what it is just by looking at the columns.  You say ABSENCES is for teachers, then why is there a student_id column and not a teacher_id column?  Why would unitid be a primary key anywhere but subjects?  In real life, a teacher would not teach just one subject.  That should be a multivalued attribute in teachers and should have its own table.  There are too many things wrong with your structure.

Comment: @devon student_id identifies the student which gets his name and id from table student. Furthermore, i can add the same teacher with another unitid to take absences for another unit. I have already coded my web application in php and a little jquery the only problem that im stuck is the one i am asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you asked the question it would just be:

```
INSERT INTO ABSENCES (unitid) VALUES (1);
```

If unitid is 1, you insert 1, it doesn't make sense without a primary key to support it.

If unitid is 1 and you want to insert the teacher id, it would make more sense, but still you don't seem to have any need for the ABSENCES table unless you are trying to insert multiple rows with the same teacher id.  In that case you need a composite key with a second field, like date for instance.

```
INSERT INTO ABSENSES (teacher_id, date) 
SELECT teacher_id, CURDATE() FROM teachers WHERE unitid = 1
```

In this case both teacher_id and date should be the primary key.

Comment: @DiellAbazi What is your use for unitid and the ABSENCES table?  What is the point of storing the same exact column in another table with no extra context?

Comment: i just edited the question please see the structure and the keypoints

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 'unitid' is a primary key in 'Teachers' table and is foreign key in 'Absences' table.

use 'mysql_insert_id()' to fetch the last inserted id from the 'Teachers' table and use the same to insert into the 'Abscences' table the following is the snippet -

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TEACHERS (...) values (...)");

$unitid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Then use the above $unitid to insert into the 'Abscences' table as follows -

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ABSCENCES (unitid,other_cols) values ('$unitid',other_values)");
```

Comment: Yes the unitid is the primary key , the problem is i want to identify the unit that the absence was taken to, via unitid becase the table teachers is related to the table subjects where unitid 1 means maths

Comment: If you don't mind can you update the question with the table structure that you are currently using for the 'Abscences'

Comment: i just did @user1696621

Comment: An alternate solution is in 'Abscences' table use 'student_id,unitid,date' columns which specifies that the particular student is abscent for particular subject on the particular date